# How do I make an interface require a key to any type value?

Tags: typescript

why am i getting this error?

```
type RequireOnlyOne<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, Keys>> & { [K in Keys]-?: Required<Pick<T, K>> & Partial<Record<Exclude<Keys, K>, undefined>> }[Keys]


interface IExample<T=any> {
    x: string,
    y: RequireOnlyOne<T, 'key'>
}

const a: IExample = {
    x: "5",
    y: {
        key: "1"
    }
}
```

Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof T'.ts(2344)

[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piqVC.png)

Comment: Remove the question mark: `externalData: Required<T, "key">;` If that's not what you meant, please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  If your question is now "why am I getting this error", the answer is that inside `IExample`, `T` is not constrained to anything, so `"key"` is not known to be one of its keys, but `RequireOnlyOne<T, K>` says that `K` must be known to be one of the keys of `T`.  So you get that error.  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: So how do I fix this error? Can you show on an example?

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing the question so that it asks exactly what you want to know.  Right now it says "why am I getting this error", although the title is asking something else, but it's not described in the question and I'm afraid that I don't quite understand what you mean by "make an interface require a key to any type value".  The error could be resolved a number of ways (e.g., loosen the constraint on `K` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nnl6BW)) but I don't really know what the goal is or what the primary question is right now.

Comment: For example, I want the key to be mandatory in the very obvious externalData object. but externalData will be an unknown type

Comment: I don't know what `externalData` is; it doesn't seem to be in the question, so if something is obvious I'm still missing it, sorry.  If you could [edit] the question to be very clear and explicit about what you want, following the guidelines for [ask] and making sure that any code you provide is a [mre] of the issue at hand, it would probably help a lot.

Comment: externalData with any type I want to have key required in this any type value

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand what you're saying, so I'll probably disengage now.  If you [edit] the question according to the suggestions I made earlier I'd be happy to take another look.  Or maybe someone else can help you with the question in its current form.  Good luck!